# How to I start/stop a song by pressing the same button (buggy implementation) in Android?

Tags: java, android

I'm learning android app development and I have a button which plays a song when clicked. The code is as follows:

```
Button b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.song);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            if(!mp.isPlaying())
                mp.stop();
            else
                mp.start();
        }
    });
```

Now, once a i press the button, the media starts and if i press it again it stops. However, it fails to stat again when i press it the 3rd time. How do i resolve this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to change `mp.stop` to `mp.pause` instead.

Comment: how do i start it from the beginning? This works tho

Comment: I would use `mp.seekTo(0);` and I would place it after `mp.pause();`

Answer (score 0):

Condition seems wrong i.e play a song if it is not playing already

```
Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.song);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
        public void onClick(View v) { 
            if(mp.isPlaying())
                mp.stop();
            else 
                mp.start();
        } 
    });
```